# Emacs and ispell: error loading german8

Tags: emacs, elisp

I get this error message when I try to load "german8" spelling dictionary while using flyspell-mode in text-mode:

```
Error in post-command-hook (flyspell-post-command-hook): (error "Error: The file "/usr/lib/aspell/deutsch\" can not be opened for reading.")
```

I've checked and there is no /usr/lib/aspell/deutsch. Ubuntu synaptic package manager offered me "aspell-de" and that didn't clear it.

Here's the code in my .emacs that started the trouble:

```
;;switch dictionaries between German and English with F8 key
(defun fd-switch-dictionary()
      (interactive)
      (let* ((dic ispell-current-dictionary)
         (change (if (string= dic "deutsch8") "english" "deutsch8")))
        (ispell-change-dictionary change)
        (message "Dictionary switched from %s to %s" dic change)
        ))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>")   'fd-switch-dictionary)
```

I can repeat this same error by simply starting flyspell-mode then trying to do ispell-change-dictionary. german8 is offered, but the message appears again:

```
 Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(Error: The file "/usr/lib/aspell/german" can not be opened for reading.)
```

Answer (score 7):

I was having exactly the same problem, but I have found a very simple workaround. I assume

- your Emacs spell checker is set to aspell, i.e., `(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")`
- the appropriate aspell dictionary is installed, for example by `apt-get install aspell-de`.

For some reason there seems to be a bug in the list of dictionaries that ispell "sees", i.e., the list of dictionaries that are available when you perform `ispell-change-dictionary`. When selecting "deutsch" it tries to load `"/usr/lib/aspell/deutsch\"`. However it looks like the aspell dictionary names have changed, since `aspell-de` now contains dictionaries called `de_DE*`. I guess the idea of @Daniel Ralston's answer is to fix this, but this didn't work for me. I also tried to pass the actual dictionary names to `ispell-change-dictionary`, but somehow it insisted on getting a dictionary from its own list and I never could convince it that my dictionary is indeed correct.

What is working for me though is a simple symlink fix. At first I wasn't sure what I'm supposed to symlink, because the error looks like it was trying to load the dictionary from a *directory* called "deutsch". But it turned out that it is actually looking for a typical aspell `.alias` file. So by using this symlink

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/aspell/de_DE.alias /usr/lib/aspell/deutsch.alias
```

I can now simply chose "deutsch" in `ispell-change-dictionary`.

Comment: The symbolic link is a simple fix that worked for me immediately.

Comment: For me, this worked: I installed the package `aspell-de` (via apt, not inside Emacs), restarted Emacs, and selected a German dictionary. No symlink needed. Is wasn't created automatically, either.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, some old and oft-used dictionary aliases seem to have been removed from the German aspell package. This has made emacs' German dictionary definitions obsolete. Try adding this to your `.emacs`:

```
(eval-after-load "ispell"
  '(add-to-list 'ispell-dictionary-alist
                '("deutsch8"
                   "[a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]" "[^a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ]" "[']" t
                  ("-C" "-d" "de_DE-neu.multi")
                  "~latin1" iso-8859-1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not really working. I still get `code`"Starting new Ispell process [/usr/bin/aspell::default] ...
Ispell process killed
Local Ispell dictionary set to deutsch8
Dictionary switched from nil to deutsch8
Starting new Ispell process [/usr/bin/aspell::deutsch8] ...
Error in post-command-hook (flyspell-post-command-hook): (error "Error: The file \"/usr/lib/aspell/deutsch\" can not be opened for reading.")"`code`

Comment: ... /usr/lib/aspell/deutsch doesn't exist. Do I need a sym link to something?

Comment: My mistake. You're trying to use the "deutsch8" dictionary, but my definition defined "german8" instead. My answer should be fixed now.

Comment: It's almost correct but the `ispell-local-dictionary-alist` variable should be used instead. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on `Arch Linux`: installed `aspell-ru` dictionary but when I did `ispell-change-dictionary russian` in emacs (`russian` being the suggested name for the dictionary), it returned with

```
Error: The file \"/usr/lib/aspell-0.60/russian\" can not be opened for reading.
```

So I did `pacman -Ql aspell-ru` and it turns out that `ru` is the name of the dictionary, not `russian`. So, `ispell-change-dictionary ru` worked fine.

Check the actual name of the dictionary file.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Elementary OS same solution install the package aspell-es and aspell-eu-es:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-es aspell-eu-es
```

all working fine.